# ColdFusion RDS through Basic Authentication

Tags: coldfusion, remote-desktop

Is it possible to enable RDS for ColdFusion 8 on a server that requires Basic Authentication? The web server is IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDS is it's own protocol and from memory has nothing to do with IIS. The authentication for RDS is managed during the initial set up/install. You can change the password using the ColdFusion administrator.

Another gotcha is that even though you enabled it during installation it sometimes remains disabled. So you need to edit the web.xml file (make a backup first). Here's a link to a kb article with detailed instructions: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/172/tn_17276.html

Hope this helps.